# render image from TagLib

Tags: grails, groovy

In a grails controller I can render an image to the response using

```
class MyController {

  def getImage = {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read('http://example.org/foo.png')
    ImageIO.write(captcha, "PNG", response.outputStream)
  }
}
```

In a GSP I can render this image using:

```
<img src="${createLink(controller: 'my', action: 'getImage')}"/>
```

I would like to write a TagLib that does something similar.

```
class MyTagLib {
  static namespace = "my"

  def getImage(attrs ->
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read('http://example.org/foo.png')            
  }    
}
```

But I can't figure out how to render this image to the response. Inside the tag class, I can only write to `out` which is an instance of `GrailsPrintWriter`, but `ImageIO.write` can only write to an `OutputStream`.

For the sake of completion, the tag above would be invoked from a GSP using

```
<my:getImage/>
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense at all: A tag library can only write to the output stream, which is usually HTML (or some other form of text).  You can't embed an image directly in the HTML (unless you encoded it using a data URI, which is not usually recommended).  If you want to dynamically serve up an image, you will still need a controller.

Comment: Conceptually, I don't see why it's OK to render binary content to the output from a controller, but not from a TagLib. But if it's not possible in practice, then I'll just make the taglib render `<img src="${createLink(controller: 'my', action: 'getImage')}"/>` though this seems a very convoluted solution.
`

Comment: Well, it's a *tag* library, so it's a library to be used in *tag*s.  If you want better abstraction, why not make it a service?  That makes more sense than a tag library, to me.  Tag libraries are used to abstract logic code away from presentational markup.

Comment: If I made it a service I wouldn't be able to call it from a GSP

Comment: OK, well, you are back to my first comment: why are you trying to output binary image data in a GSP?  A GSP is designed to render textual data.  I think there's a logic disconnect here.  When you put content on the web, you send the HTML, which has references to the image data.  The image data is sent in a separate request.  This isn't a problem related to taglibs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a writer instance of the `GrailsPrintWriter`, by doing `new WriterOutputStream(out)`. Try this:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new URL('http://www.google.de/images/srpr/logo3w.png'))
ImageIO.write(image, "png", new WriterOutputStream(out))
```

(tested in grails 2.0)

Comment: When I try using the code, the byte text of the image is just displayed on my page? Am I missing something?

Comment: You cannot inline print an image within an html file (or you dont want to). therefore this code shows how to do this within a controller action, which has to be referenced using `<img src="${createLink(controller: 'my', action: 'getImage')}"/>`